# Getting text of a table quickly in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table, webdriver

I'm trying to parse a number of columns in a table into a dictionary using Selenium, but what I have seems slow.  I'm using python, Selenium 2.0, and webdriver.Chrome()

```
table = self.driver.find_element_by_id("thetable")
    # now get all the TR elements from the table
    all_rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")

    # and iterate over them, getting the cells
    for row in all_rows:
        cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        # slowwwwwwwwwwwwww
        dict_value = {'0th': cells[0].text,
                 '1st': cells[1].text,
                 '2nd': cells[2].text,
                 '3rd': cells[3].text,
                 '6th': cells[6].text,
                 '7th': cells[7].text,
                 '10th': cells[10].text}
```

The problem seems to be getting the 'text' attribute of each td element.  Is there a faster way?

Comment: Are you getting any exception? or just slow execution? If it is just slow then searching element with `xpath` or `css` can be little faster.

Comment: No exception, it just takes a while to process each row.

Comment: Note that row.find_elements_by_tag_name is quite quick.  It's just the 'cells[#].text' that slows everything down

Comment: To be specific, each cells[#].text takes ~.035 seconds, which adds up to .245 seconds per row.  When I'm parsing a lot of rows, things get slow.

Comment: try using `getAttribute()` something like `element.get_attribute('value')`

Comment: FWIW, `.text` is one of the most computationally expensive things Selenium has to do, so it's going to have some performance implication.

Comment: As an alternative, get everything in JavaScript once with `execute_script`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternative option.

If later (after the loop), you don't need interactiveness that selenium provides you with - you can pass the current [HTML source code](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) of the page to [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), which is known for it's speed. Example:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
for row in root.xpath('.//table[@id="thetable"]//tr'):
    cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()')
    dict_value = {'0th': cells[0],
                  '1st': cells[1],
                  '2nd': cells[2],
                  '3rd': cells[3],
                  '6th': cells[6],
                  '7th': cells[7],
                  '10th': cells[10]}
```

Comment: @PearSquirrel great! Have you measured how much faster does it work comparing to pure-selenium approach? Thanks.

Comment: It used to take ~5 seconds to process, now it takes ~.1 seconds

Comment: I'm getting an index out of range error even with only two indicies (0,1) any ideas? My table has enough data.

Comment: Really cool stuff. I loved how fast this went. From 20 seconds to 2.