# Selenium's element returns text too slow

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

- Chrome version: 105.0.5195.102
- Selenium == 4.4.3
- Python == 3.9.12

In a certain page, ***'element.text'*** takes ~0.x seconds which is unbearable. I suppose ***'element.text'*** should return literally just a text from a cached page so couldn't understand it takes so long time. **How can I make it faster?**

Here are similar QNAs but I need to solve the problem just with Selenium.

- [Parse text with BeatufulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055124/12472146)
- [Parse text with lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27594210/12472146)

Another question: **Why every 'element.text' takes different times?**

For example,

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(cwd=True)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.bbc.com/")

t0 = time.time()
e = wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#page > section.module.module--header > h2")
print(time.time()-t0)

for i in range(10):
    t0 = time.time()
    txt = e.text
    print(time.time()-t0)
    # This prints different result for every loop.

wd.quit()
```

Comment: Try using `.get_attribute('innerText')` instead of `.text`

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can be a bit slow because it does NOT work directly with Chrome. The communication is made via channel which is the Chrome web driver.

If you wish to work with a faster and better plugin for Automation try using `PlayWright`.

Another thing you can try is to find your element directly, and not using a long CSS or long Xpath expression. The longer your expression will be -> the longer it will take to find it and its text

Answer (score 0):

I see the following output for your code:

```py
0.0139617919921875
0.01196908950805664
0.003988742828369141
0.004987955093383789
0.003988027572631836
0.0039899349212646484
0.003989219665527344
0.004987955093383789
0.003987789154052734
0.003989696502685547
0.0049860477447509766
```

The first 2 times are about 12-14 milliseconds while the others are about 4 milliseconds.
The first action

```py
wd.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#page > section.module.module--header > h2")
```

is polling the DOM until it finds there element matching the given locator.
While the `txt = e.text` line uses already existing reference to the element on the page, so it does not perform any polling / searching, just access an element on the page via the existing reference (pointer) that's why it takes significantly less time.
Why the second time is long as the first I don't sure I know.
I run this test several times, got different outputs but mainly the picture was the +- same.

Comment: Yes, I understand this: "While the txt = e.text line uses already existing reference to the element on the page". "e.txt" in the example takes few milliseconds is acceptable but my actual case takes few 'hundreds' of milliseconds. (I cannot afford you the actual page because it is private one.)  I don't understand why because the element had been already referenced as you said.

Comment: That's strange. Seems it's some issue with the page /site you are working on domain, maybe special page structure. I don't know.